# I would like to increase the rowHeight as I add new cells to UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios

I would like one cell where rowHeight is equal to the height of the UITableView.
Add I add new cells, the roWHeight is then divided by the total amount of cells I have.

in my viewDidLoad where I set the default height. I have:

```
myCellHeightNum = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:100];
//not sure how to get the height of the UITableView so i set it to 100
```

in my `-(IBAction) AddCell` method I have:

```
[myTableView beginUpdates];
double value = [myCellHeightNum doubleValue];
myCellHeightNum = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:value * value / numOfCells];
 [myTableView reloadData];
```

idk, any ideas.

Thanks,

Ben

Comment: What about a custom cell that is edited in the cellFroRowAtIndexPath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write this function

> ```
> -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
>   double value = [myCellHeightNum doubleValue];
>   myCellHeightNum = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:value * value / numOfCells];
>   return [myCellHeightNum floatValue];
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

use this method

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: Note, though, that this method is called for every cell *before* the table is displayed, so don't do any expensive calculations here or your app will appear to hang.